# Google Pay integration with Vantiv Gateway

Tags: android, payment-gateway, google-pay, worldpay

I am getting a transaction failed message when I request payment token google pay. I did use real card information in the TEST ENVIRONMENT. Below is the response.

[image]

Is there any limitation on the country(Srilanka) in TEST environement to enable google pay functionality on our app.?

I did follow below documentation and source code.
Development Notes:

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist

Sample Source Code.

https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart/tree/master/kotlin

Please give me your thoughts on this PLEASE.

Comment: Can you reproduce in jsfiddle and share a link? You can use the following as a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/fw5t6caL/

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to this, Is provided jsfilddle example working for you.? Can you let me know, Is country depends on this. I think, i am getting location issue for google api.

Comment: It works for me, but I am based in the US. Google Pay does have restricted payment methods based on country. One of the things that you can try is to change the country in your [Google Pay payment profile](https://pay.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/settings) or set up a new payment profile.

Comment: Thank you, What did you use for a card? it is an actual card or testing card? Please confirm.

Comment: I used a real card.